# Need help indenting bubble for group table view iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using the group table view in my app, and I want to indent a section.  Currently, I'm using the indentationlevel parameter, but that's indenting the text within the section.  Please see this link to an image that helps explain what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if group table views behave any differently than standard table views, but you might want to look into custom cell initialization on the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and adjust the cell's frame to have a larger x coordinate and a smaller width...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a grouped table view. The only thing that you really can do it to manually adjust the cell's frame in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method depending on the section.